# Running 2 5V USB battery power packs, Can I use them in parallel

Tags: power, usb

Can I run two 5v power packs in parallel to give me more mAh's (Time)? Or will one try and charge the other?

[Example](http://www.ianker.com/External%20Batteries/category-c1-s1)

I.E. connect both 5V lines together, both GND lines together to my device

Comment: s/charge/destroy/

Comment: Id rather recommend you buying a empty battery bank from China for 3$ , take the batteries out of your bank ( they have to use the same) and put them into the new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly recommend against paralleling two of the typical "power bank" devices. A far better strategy is to use one till it is depleted and then unplug it and switch over to the other one.

There are a good number of reasons for not doing this:

1) Many power banks use voltage converter circuits of questionable design. I've tested a few that cannot even output 5V unless they have no load and under even moderate load will drop to even as low as 4.6V.

2) Power banks are highly likely to output different voltages that vary with the amount of charge left in their internal batteries. This is due in part to the crappy circuit design as mentioned above. When the voltages are not the same on the outputs then trying to parallel the outputs will lead to problems. The least of which could be that one unit supplies all the load till it has depleted more than the others.

3) It is never a good idea to parallel up the outputs of switching power supplies. The behavior of one in trying to adjust the output voltage could interact with the other and even lead to a detrimental oscillatory behavior. Only parallel supplies that are manufacturer specified by design to support parallel operation. The most robust of these have a shared sense line that strings between the paralleled supplies to make them all play nice with each other. Power banks, which do contain switching power outputs, most certainly do not have that sharing capability.

Comment: We have decided to daisy chain the output of the 1st battery to the input of the second, rather than trying to try them together. Thanks for the info

Comment: I am not sure that daisy chaining makes much sense. Seems silly to pay the price of energy conversion from VBAT in the first unit to 5V only to then use that to be paying for an second energy conversion back to VBAT for charging. I would get rid of the concept of trying to use two battery banks at the same time. If you need more capacity get something that provides it. Possibly you need a good size sealed lead acid battery followed by an efficient 12V to 5V step down converter.

Comment: Welcome to the future! This answer is now six years old, and I suspect it's no longer accurate. I have a number of 99-watt-hour lithium-ion power banks that output via a pair of standard USB-A receptacles, and they're all based on the [Injoinic IP5306 SoC](https://easyeda.com/wagiminator/ip5306-lipo-charger-booster-usb-c) or one of its variants. When fully charged, these deliver 5.1 V, according to my multimeter battery-tester function. The chip also includes various circuit fail-safes. Furthermore, a decent boost converter isn't going to vary its output voltage; either it's on or it's off.

Comment: @jdmc - I have to disagree with you regarding this answer, The advice there regarding to not parallel power supply outputs (as in power banks for this question) is still 100% accurate. You are however valid in expressing that many quality power banks exist that are able to hold their output voltage constant. With that said I am still pretty sure that there are just as many with cheap and crappy designs that will act like I described in my answer.,

Comment: @MichaelKaras : I agree that it's not something that should be attempted without carefully checking the equipment first. Yesterday, I experimented with a few pairs of matching powerbanks with the IP5306 chip as I mentioned above, connected in parallel to a 2-watt load. Nothing bad happened; in fact, I could connect a 2nd and then disconnect the 1st without a power cutoff to the load, which was nice. But one bank or the other perceives that it's not doing anything, and soon turns itself off. Drat!