# Two same capacity/model powerbank. Output connected via Y connector (parallel)

Tags: powerbanks

If I have 2 same capacity/model of power bank and combine the output via Y connector (parallel), will there be any issue?

Comment: Typically you must not do that.  These are almost always switching power supplies and their control loops are likely to interact poorly.  But questions on the *usage* of products are off topic.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188203/running-2-5v-usb-battery-power-packs-can-i-use-them-in-parallel